# How to create a .net object that serialises to the following using web.api

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

How do I create a .net object that will serialise to the following using web api

```
<xml>
<merchant>
<product></product>
<uri></uri>
<product></product>
<uri></uri>
<product></product>
<uri></uri>
</merchant>
```

Comment: You don't - thats not valid xml for serialization/deserialization to a list of objects

Answer (score 1):

Use this site to generate your C# object: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Use the `XmlSerializer` to serialize or deserialize into an Object.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourType));

// From XML
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(""))
{
    var yourTypeCollection = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

// To XML
using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry the output from this wouldn't work, it gives 2 list of product and uri but the spec says that the uri should follow the product tag. Crazy I know but that's what they expect.

Comment: If they are using non-standard serialization rules, then it gets a bit ugly. Typically, you'll have to write your own plugin or code to generate the string at that point. I wish I had better news.

Comment: There might be a solution, if you alter the generated object slightly. Let me add a sample.